# Passing multiple values to a function

Tags: python, ms-word

I'm trying to use a find and replace with win32com.client in Python to replace 2 strings in a word document.  basiclaly my test document has 'First Name' & 'Last Name' and from that I'm creating a new document that replaces the two with 'John' & 'Smith', but only the first name gets changed.  I'm new to python, so I'm sure it's something obvious I'm doing wrong.  I've been at this for some time, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import win32com.client

word = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Word.Application")
word.Visible = True
word.DisplayAlerts = 0
word.Documents.Open("C:\TEMP\Test.docx")

def replace(find_str, replace_str):
    find = word.Selection.Find
    find.Text = find_str
    find.Replacement.Text = replace_str
    find.Execute(Replace=1, Forward=True)

replace('First Name', 'John')

replace('Last Name', 'Smith')

word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs('C:\TEMP\Test2.docx')
word.Quit()
```

Comment: can this be that Replace=1 replace only first occurance?

Comment: msdn states that replace specifies how many replacements are to be made: one, all, or none. I tried Replace=2 and that did the trick.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just using

```
find.Execute(Replace=2, Forward=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can

```
o = open("C:\TEMP\Test.docx","a") #open for append
for line in open("file"):
   line = line.replace("someword","newword") # set your own names here
   o.write(line + "\n") 
o.close()
```

so no need to redefine a `replace` method.

Comment: `.docx` is not a text file.